# div ignoring parents width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have container that contains 2 divs(it include some content). Left - image, right - overview and list of movies. Container has next properties: width 100%, max-width - 1300px, display: flex. But when i add movie list to right div its ignoring parent max-width and stretches to full width. When i add width 70% to rigth div, it helps, but i do not want to set strict values

Screen
https://prnt.sc/w01j86

```
Container props: { display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400; }

Right div props : {display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin: 8rem 3rem;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    -webkit-flex: auto;
    -ms-flex: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your CSS in `Right div props :`